Is it possible to step through ASP.NET Core's model binding process and if so, how?
Sometimes, when sending data to the server for an OnPost, the binding fails and all the properties of the object have default values. I find debugging this issue very tedious and it would be helpful if I could set a breakpoint somewhere and walk through the binding process to see what's tripping it up.
Sometimes the solution to the binding issue leaves me just as confused.
For example, here's my OnPost function:
public async Task<JsonResult> OnPostSaveFXRateAsync(Fxrates fxRate)
{
    fxRate.LastUpdatedBy = User.Identity.Name;

    bool isSuccess = await AL.SaveAndLogEntityAsync<Fxrates, int>(fxRate, Constants.Audit_Module_ControlCenter, User.Identity.Name);

    return new JsonResult(new { success = isSuccess });
}

This is the Ajax call:
onClickSave = (e) =>
{
    let fxDate = $('#FXRate_Fxdate').data('kendoDatePicker').value();

    let formData =
    {
            Id: parseInt($('#FXRate_Id').val()),
            Fxdate: fxDate?.toYYYYMMDD(),
            FiscalPeriodTypeId: $('#FXRate_FiscalPeriodTypeId').val(),
            FromCurrencyId: $('#FXRate_FromCurrencyId').val(),
            ToCurrencyId: $('#FXRate_ToCurrencyId').val(),
            Fxrate: parseFloat($('#FXRate_Fxrate').val())
    };

    console.log(formData);

    let validator = $('#frmFXRate').kendoValidator().data('kendoValidator');
    console.log(validator);

    if (validator.validate())
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Admin/ControlCenter/FXRateDetails?handler=SaveFXRate',
            data: formData,
            content: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            headers: { 'RequestVerificationToken': $("input[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val() },
            success: function (response)
            {
                console.log('save successful');
                window.parent.$('#FXRatesGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
                window.parent.$("#DetailsWnd").data("kendoWindow").close();
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                console.log('Save failed');
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        console.log('Form data invalid');
    }
}

I have Ajax calls that look just like this in a dozen other places and they all work fine, but the model binding fails here. I've verified that all the field names and types match.
The fix that made the binding work was to wrap the individual fields of formData in an object with the same name as the OnPost parameter like this:
    let formData =
    {
        fxRate: {
            Id: parseInt($('#FXRate_Id').val()),
            Fxdate: fxDate?.toYYYYMMDD(),
            FiscalPeriodTypeId: $('#FXRate_FiscalPeriodTypeId').val(),
            FromCurrencyId: $('#FXRate_FromCurrencyId').val(),
            ToCurrencyId: $('#FXRate_ToCurrencyId').val(),
            Fxrate: parseFloat($('#FXRate_Fxrate').val())
        }
    };

If I had to do this everywhere, then fine, that's just how the binding works. But I don't understand why I had to do that here and only here. What is so special about this one time?
For completion's sake, here's the class Fxrates (an Entity Framework class):
public partial class Fxrates
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime Fxdate { get; set; }

    public string FiscalPeriodTypeId { get; set; }
    public string FromCurrencyId { get; set; }
    public string ToCurrencyId { get; set; }

    public decimal Fxrate { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public string LastUpdatedBy { get; set; }

    public virtual FiscalPeriodType FiscalPeriodType { get; set; }
    public virtual Currency FromCurrency { get; set; }
    public virtual User LastUpdatedByNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual Currency ToCurrency { get; set; }
}

If I could step through the binding process perhaps I'd have a better understanding of why particular instances such as this one fail, while others do not.

I don't know if this will work, but try positioning the cursor on the set; part of the property definition and setting a breakpoint. If that fails, trying converting some of your properties to the old-fashioned format (with an explicit backing store field and setters that use the value keyword)

So many people get caught up in this, eg my last answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78547368/495455 - short answer is you can't debug into without the asp.net code, but if you setup a Rest Client with all the FrontEnd api calls that will be a good reference to check why something fails. It might help your understanding to try a project where you implement your own binding https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/6372 but

In ASP.NET Core, model binding is automatically matched based on the structure of the request data and the structure of the controller action parameters.
When you send a request, the format of the data must match the format expected by the server. If the controller action parameter is a complex object (such as Fxrates), the data sent must also match the structure of this object. In your controller, the OnPostSaveFXRateAsync method expects an Fxrates object, so the structure of the formData in the AJAX request needs to be consistent with it, which is why this is required. For more information on model binding and the process, you can refer to these documents ：document1,document2.
If you want to know more clearly where the problem occurs in the model binding process, you can set breakpoints on the method and use the network option of the browser developer tools to inspect the actual request data sent to the server and the server's response and compare the data structure.
Here is a sample process you can refer to：
When I submit the relevant data, I can observe the data I submitted in the payload of the network option:

Relevant data information can be captured at the breakpoint:


Log the RAW request data, you will find quickly what is missing.
Alternatively, do the mapping manually: remove the Fxrates fxRate from the method, and create it manually inside the function using data from httpcontext.
I am betting though, that the problem is a date that is not recognized as a date :-)
